# ngxs, redux dev tools show previous state

Tags: angular5, ngxs

Here is a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-example-basic).

In console.log the state is updated correctly. Also the template is updated correctly.

In redux dev tools the state is updated with a delay of a dispatch.

To be more clear, the initial state is:

```
{data: [], loading: false, counter: 0}
```

When I click on the button 'Fetch', the component dispatches two events:

```
this.ngxs.dispatch(new LoadingData());
this.ngxs.dispatch(new GetData());
```

LoadingData just empty data array and set loading to true:

```
@Mutation(LoadingData)
loadingData(state){
    state.data = [];
    state.loading = true;
}
```

In console and in template the state is updated right, but in redux dev tools loading is still false:

[image]

GetData is an Action that executes a service method that returns an Observable then dispatch two events DataSuccess and Increase :

```
@Action(GetData)
getData(state){
  return this.as.list().map(data => [
    new DataSuccess(data),
    new Increase(),
  ]);
}
```

Only now, In redux dev tools loading is set to true

Increase just increment counter and DataSuccess set loading to false and populate data array:

```
@Mutation(Increase)
increase(state){
  state.counter = state.counter + 1;
}

@Mutation(DataSuccess)
dataSuccess(state, {payload}){
  state.data = payload;
  state.loading = false;
}
```

DataSuccess is executed before Increase. In redux dev tools in DataSuccess loading is still set to true and data array is still empty.

In redux dev tools in Increase data array is finally populated but counter is set to 0.

So redux dev tools always show the previous state. I'm new to redux/ngrx/ngxs so I don't know if this behaviour is my fault. I'd really appreciate any hint or correction to make it work in the right way.

Comment: Everything looks normal to me. What is your question?

Comment: I don't think it's normal to see in redux dev tools the wrong state (the previous state to be more precise). Please take a look at updated question or execute the example in a browser with redux dev tools extension enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in the framework, it has been resolved in latest :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turned out that I needed to change setting to "Autoselect instances" instead of "Instance 1". I don't know why, but devtools extension always changes instance to different than "Autoselect instances" so I have to manually set it each time
[image]